# Fragment en foco

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment

Tengo una aplicación con varios fragment, al deslizar la pantalla horizontalmente van apareciendo y cada uno tiene un color de fondo , quiero que al estar uno en foco, que aparezca un texto (Toast), esto se puede ?

Comment: prueba agregando el toast dentro de onCreateView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si el manejo de los fragmentos lo hacés con un ViewPager tenés dos posibilidades, si trabajás con el API 24.1.0 o superior podés utilizar el método addOnPageChangeListener para que te "avise" cuando cambia de fragmento, algo así:

```
mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        //Si es el fragmento que necesitás, mostrás el mensaje
    }
});
```

Pero si usás una API anterior podés utilizarlo así:

```
mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        //Si es el fragmento que necesitás, mostrás el mensaje
    }
});
```

Espero te sirva.

¡Suerte!

Comment: Muchas gracias por su pronta respuesta !, funcionó perfecto!